# Access Text Field outside the package?

Tags: java

I have a question in java:

Is it possible to access a java text field outside the package? how to do that?

Example: a package called users has a text field called username .... i want to access that field in another package called employee.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: what is the good action to make.... using protected is better or public ??

Comment: show your tried code first

Comment: protected cannot be accessed... editor shows me to use public and it is good... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! it's possible to access a java text field outside the package.
To access the Text-Field outside the package You can use **public keyword**
Example:-
public JTextField textField;

Above textField member can access any package.

For [More Details Visit link.](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/access-modifier-in-java/)